# TransactionBuilder becomes immutable after sending

Tags: corda

I need several nodes to build one transaction. To achieve that I create a `TransactionBuilder` and pass it to nodes that then add their states to it.

This seems to be a legit practice since the [official documentation](https://docs.corda.net/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.core.transactions/-transaction-builder/) mentions `TransactionBuilder` is intended to be passed around contracts that may edit it by adding new states/commands.

I've added `TransactionBuilder` to the serialization white-list so that Corda can send/receive it.

However when running a unit test the network throws this exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.add(Collections.java:1055)
at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.addInputState(TransactionBuilder.kt:149)
```

I looked into it in debugger, and the type of the builder after it has been received is `UnmodifiableList`.

My workaroand is to copy the builder after receiving it.

But why it works like that? Did I interpreted the documentation wrong?

We use Corda 3.3

Comment: Yeah. It's immutable, you've to copy the TxBuilder, do your changes to it and then send it back over the wire. In case after receiving the TxBuilder, something needs to be added to the Txbuilder, you'll have to copy it again and make changes to it

Comment: @Kid101 Why do we need those ceremonies and why they are not mentioned in the docs?

Comment: I'm not sure either, you can actually raise an issue on git if you want. but instead of sending TxBuilder why not use send and receive Transaction Flow?

Comment: SendTransactionFlow works with a signed transaction, while I need to add states to it, which must happen before signing

Comment: yeah, that's correct but that's how it should be used.  Signed Tx can be created into a Ledger tx which will get you the states you want. you can always sign your tx builder twice only this time it have the state you received from your counterparty.

Comment: @Kid101 Sorry, I don't follow what you are saying. Could you post an answer to this question with a code sample of your proposed solution? That would make discussing it much easier

Answer (score 1):

Corda serialises objects at various points (e.g. when they are sent or received between nodes within flows, when they are sent via RPC) using its own serialisation framework.

In Java, if you receive a serialised object where one of the fields is a `List`, it is not possible to check whether the list in question was originally mutable or immutable. In Corda, we therefore default to deserialising such lists as immutable lists.

You should make a copy of the original `TransactionBuilder`, as you are already doing.

Comment: Hey Joel . I got the solution, but can you please explain it a little more as to why it happens. Where are we receiving serialized object.

Comment: Thanks, that makes much more sense now. :)